# Is this class of groups already in the literature or specified by standard conditions?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, equivariant-homotopy

In recent work
[Lifting $N_\infty$ operads from conjugacy data](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.06798) on homotopical combinatorics / $N_\infty$ operads in equivariant homotopy theory, collaborators
Scott Balchin, Ethan MacBrough, and I identified a class of groups we call *lossless*. Here is our definition:

> A group $G$ is *lossless* when for all $K\le H\le G$ and $g\in G$ such that $gKg^{-1}\le H$, there exists $h\in N_G(H)$ (the normalizer of $H$ in $G$) such that $hKh^{-1} = gKg^{-1}$.

Here are our questions:

> Is this class of groups (a) studied elsewhere in the literature (presumably under a different name)? or (b) specified by some more familiar string of conditions/adjectives?

For our purposes, we would be happy to restrict to $G$ finite.

We already know (see §2.2 of [the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.06798)) that finite solvable T-groups, $p$-groups of order at most $p^3$, and groups with cyclic normal subgroups of prime index are lossless. The group $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_7)$ is *lossy* (i.e. not lossless) and we give a class of $p$-groups of order $p^4$ which are lossy in Example 2.18.

Comment: This is somewhat related to "control of fusion", I think.

Comment: @SamHopkins - Good catch! I have fixed a typo in the definition of lossless. When $gKg^{-1}\le H$ for some $g\in G$, we in fact require $h\in N_G(H)$ such that $gKg^{-1} = hKh^{-1}$.

Comment: @NeilStrickland - Yes, they do look to be related, but it seems that control of fusion is an elementwise condition whereas our condition is an equality of sets.

Comment: In finite group theory, ( and transfer, etc), often control of fusion can be setwise. So, here a finite group theorist might say that for each subgroup $H$ of $G$ the fusion of subgroups of $H$ within $G$ is controlled by $N_{G}(H)$. It is true that in work of Alperin and others, and later work on fusion systems, we need control of strong fusion (I've always felt that strong control of fusion would be a better expression), wher we require $h$ and $g$ ( as in your definition) to induce the same conjugation elementwise on $K$ , that is, $h^{-1}g \in C_{G}(K)$).

Comment: Thanks, @GeoffRobinson. We will definitely look into the control of fusion (of subgroups) perspective! Do you know of any papers that explicitly use such a condition?

Comment: Often in finite group theory, it is how the fusion of subgroups ( or sometimes just individual elements) of a fixed Sylow $p$-subgroup $S$ of $G$ is effected within $G$ which is important.  In the more genral setting of dealing with all subgroups, as you seem to, then paper of people like A. Dress on idempotents in the Burnside ring of a finite group may be relevant to you (and there have been much work on uses of the Burnside ring in group  representation theory over the decades since)

Comment: Call $P(H,K)$ the given condition (so "lossless" means that $P(H,K)$ holds for all $K\le H\le G$). Then $P(H,K)$ is trivial when $H$ is normal. Note that the condition $P(H,H)$ is trivial when $H$ is finite but fails when there exists $g\in G$ such that $gHg^{-1}<H$. The existence of a subgroup conjugate to a proper subgroup of itself is quite frequent for infinite groups (e.g. every group with a nonabelian free subgroup, and many others). Anyway, a f.g. group in which every proper subgroup is cyclic, or in which every proper subgroup is finite (cf. Tarski monsters) is lossless.

Comment: @YCor: I don't understand your last comment; didn't Kyle say he knows examples of lossy finite groups?

Comment: @SamHopkins So what? There's no contradiction. Lossy means that $P(H,K)$ fails for some $K\le H\le G$. I mentioned that $P(H,H)$ holds whenever $G$ is finite but can fail for $G$ infinite.

Comment: @YCor: Sorry I must be reading your comment wrong then; I thought you said "a finitely generated group [...] in which every proper subgroup is finite is lossless." That would seem to include all finite groups, no?

Comment: @SamHopkins oops, you're right, I wasn't careful. I should have said only: a f.g. group in which every proper subgroup is cyclic.